# Google web toolkit code inspection

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, code-analysis

I've got an old gwt-based project, which was initially created using gwt-1.4.
Project uses RPC to send the data across the wire. But Services classes and it's implementations, frequently applying raw use of collections or just Object to send data, like this:

```
public static long queryCount(String queryStr, Map<String, Object> params)
```

or this:

```
 public List<CBobj> queryLazy(String query, Map params)

 public void setSigningPerson(Long id, AsyncCallback async)
```

etc.

I need to make it use newest GWT version (now it's GWT-2.8.2), and rewrite non-generic methods.

The problem is: when I use Idea> Analyze > Inspect code (to find all broken places) it works on GWT-2.5-1 level, which was already successfully implemented - project is now working on GWT 2.5.1.

I've fixed all code problems that 2.5.1 offres to me. After that I did replace all libraries and links, so im sure now it works on 2.8.2. (i can say it because new methods from new gwt like GWT.debugger() is recognized by idea) I couldn't find anything about Inspect Code and how it works.

Project compiles as usual, I dont know why, I guess GWT-2.8.2 should've broke it, I can say it because I tried to implement new GWT before, everything got broke when old gwt was replaced with new one, I couldn't compile and inspection was pointing to all those non-generic places. Now it just ignoring it.

Thank you!

P.S I'm sure I have a check at "Google Web Toolkit issues" box, in inspection dialog, but it shows only gwt2-5-1 lvl problems.

Comment: Raw methods are okay - they are legal Java and legal GWT (though they may not be optimal). To better find usages of raw types, you don't need to run the GWT inspections, but just the Java inspections that Eclipse offers.

Comment: As far as I know, gwt 2.5.1+ requires generic types instead of Objects, this is the problem. Project is quite big, simple inspection wouldn't help, i need to see problems related only to gwit.

Comment: If all you are talking about is `AsyncCallback` being raw in an RPC call, that might be true, but in general GWT has no problem with raw generics. To find all cases of raw `AsyncCallback`, simply search your codebase for `AsyncCallback `, with that space at the end to avoid any `<>` correctly parameterized instances.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the thing that is bothering me, is what would happen if I pass a non-serializable object inside Map through `Map params` in the method signature. For example `Map <String, Object>` . Or may be the Object can be used like link, that wraps real serializable class, and this is a legal way? To be totaly specific here is example : `MyClass implements Serializable; Object obj = new MyClass();` is obj serializable here?

Comment: I'll write that, and the original answer, up in an answer for you - but the best thing to do here would be to try it so you understand more about how RPC works.